# How to let backend APIs communicate with each other?

Tags: architecture, server, backend

I'm building a complicated frontend-backend application of which both the frontend and backend should be highly scalable and reusable. To serve these two requirements, I'm splitting the backend into multiple APIs where each API has it's own purpose (e.g. Registration, Login, Email verification, email etc.).

These APIs may be distributed across multiple machines (e.g. the LoginAPI is on machine A, registration API on machine B). The APIs may also have a dependency to one another. For example: the Email Verification API (shorthand: EVA) has a dependency to the Email API (shorthand: EA) in order to send emails.

What I am looking into right now is how to properly let these APIs communicate with one another. Coming back to the above example where EVA makes use of EA, I don't think it is a good idea to hardcode the URL to EA within EVA. Also making the URL to EA configurable doesn't seem like a good idea because if more and more APIs start depending on EA, then when EA moves to a different location on the network, all the APIs that depend on it have to be reconfigured.

What I am tempted to build is a central gateway API that is aware of the network location of all internally accessible APIs (separated from the publicly available gateway API due to security reasons). When for example EVA wants to communicate with EA, it does so sending an API identifier for EA (e.g. a relative path) along with the request payload to the gateway, which then resolves this identifier (or relative path) into a network location and forwards the request.

I'm wondering if this is a good strategy to use for my use-case or if you guys have any alternative solutions that may be a better fit to my situation. I'm curious to see what other approaches are.

Comment: Your configuration strategy is the better one, along with blue/green deployments. In the scenario where the network address moves (btw Hello DNS updates), you can deploy the service in the new location, redeploy each of the dependent services in a rolling cascade, then decomission the old service. If something goes wrong you can rollback.

Comment: What you need (IMO) is a [Service Discovery](https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-in-a-microservices-architecture/).

Comment: @Laiv interesting topic, i'll read up on that further. Cheers :)

Comment: or DNS rather than hard coded server/cluster names for your locations

Answer (score 1):

Think of any part as an independent software that could connect to any other.

The point is the API to be as generic and decoupled from a particular implementation as possible, so making changes in any part is made easier.

For that you will want the API not to define policy, just mechanisms. And let the policy be defined by the component closest to what the user employs.